# Pascal: change TProcess description?

Tags: process, filenames, executable, pascal

Is there a way to change the process description (Shown in the Task Manager > Processes (Depends on OS) > Description)? If I create a TProcess, using

```
Process1:=TProcess.Create(NIL);
```

then the description will most likely be the same as the executable's name.

Comment: What Pascal compiler are you using? Any answer will be dependent on the features of the compiler/linker being used.

Comment: TProcess is a FCL class and (on Windows) a wrapper for createprocess+piping.  It is FPC, but it is relatively easily ported, and I use a ported Windows only version also with Delphi.  So probably just an extra attribute (platform;) and a winapi call needs to be added.

Comment: I am using Lazarus, the graphical Pascal interface. I've heard of DLL injection and other methods. Are those possible to change the description?

Comment: The Task Manager's Process tab shows the information (if available) from the version resource's `FileDescription`. It's available on Windows by adding a version resource (via a resource compiler or `{$R}` directive) to your application. I don't use Lazarus, so I can't tell you how to do so there, but in the Delphi IDE it's done in *Project->Options->Version Info* by checking *Include version information in project* and filling in the fields in the dialog and then building the project.

Comment: This, indeed, is an OS dependent solution, and @KenWhite 's comment is relevant on Windows 7 (tested). Thanks!